# Scroll to a page in UICollectionView with paging enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to pass a number(page number) from a view controller to a another view controller which has `UICollectionView` with `paging enabled` option. My code does scroll to a page but the contents are not centered , here is my code :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let currentPage = 4
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: currentPage , section: 0) as IndexPath
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
}
```

Result :

[image]

What I Need :

[image]

**Solution :**

```
collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:  CGFloat(currentPage) * collectionView.bounds.size.width , y: 0), animated: false)
```

**EDITED**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: 321 , height: 321)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to scroll like this:

```
collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:  currentPage * itemSize, y: 0), animated: false)
```

Where `itemSize` is the size of the item in the collection view. Also if you have spacing between each item you should add that as well when you calculate the `x`

Edit: you need to use `itemSize.width` and in case you need to cast currentPage to `CGFloat` like this `CGFloat(currentPage)`

Comment: you need to use `itemSize.width`and in case you need to cast `currentPage ` to `CGFloat` like this `CGFloat(currentPage)`

Comment: Thanks but instead of itemSize , I mentioned `collectionView.bounds.size.width` now it works fine.

Comment: I just found another problem ! this line of code only works in iPhone 4.7" screens !!!! Why ? The selected device in storyboard is iPhone 7 but I added constraint . so why this happens ?

Comment: this only works like you said if you have a constant size for your item... if you want the item to be full width on all devices you need to create it so in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` functions so a good size for you item would be like this `return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 150)`, this will have dynamic width (depending on screen size) and static height

Comment: you should not use constant for `width`

Comment: If change it to var `var size = CGSize(width: 321 , height: 321)` xcode compiler warns me !

Comment: you still use 321 ... which is constant ... constant value ... no matter what ... please read about swift basics

Comment: Sorry I don't understand would you write it ? are you int or float ? `321.0` ?

Comment: if you want your cell to be about the size of the screen ... on different devices, that have a different size ... would you just take a random number at give it to the cell width ? I recommend you to create a question on how to create UICollectionView with dynamic cell size or read up on that